# REST and PDF Reports

Tags: rest

I'm developing a REST API where one of my calls look like `/api/1/orders/1234`. The result is returned in Json format by default and displayed at the browser window with the help of AngularJS.

At this specific case, I must generate a PDF version of the resource, which will be printed, signed (by hand) and stored for legal purposes. What is the recommended way of doing this, considering this call contains every data needed to generate the report?

My guess, is that a PDF version is simply another format of the resource, and simply adding a query parameter (`?format=pdf`) should be enough and not so ugly. Is there a better way (don't care if harder or easier to implement, specially server side)?.

I couldn't find a recommended way of doing this anywhere, so any hint would be good. Sorry if this question is too much of a "opinion based question".

Comment: content-type: application/pdf

Comment: @WonTonSoup No, `Content-Type` specifies the MIME of the body of the request/response. Maybe you meant `Accept`, but the problem is that some clients does not support custom `Accept` fields.

Answer (score 1):

The 'correct' way would be using the Request Header-field `Accept: application/pdf` which allows for content negotiation.

Your suggestion of `api/1/orders/1234?format=pdf` could work, though there is a bit cleaner solution `api/1/orders/1234.pdf`

Depending if you have control over the clients or not, (I write my Perl CLI client as well) I would not be bothered about those that don't support the full HTTP specs. As long as we feel obligated to support crappy clients, there will be no urge to upgrade those clients.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to handle this kind of situation is to use [content negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4).

> When responses convey payload information the origin server often has
> different ways of representing that information; for example, in
> different formats. For this reason, HTTP provides mechanisms for
> content negotiation.

[Apache HTTPD content negotiation documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) provides some good examples (you can ignore the configuration details if you are not using httpd). This will work nicely if you API is consumed by application clients.

So when the client wants the json representation, it can request

```
GET /api/1/orders/1234 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Accept: application/json
```

and when the client wants the pdf representation, it can request

```
GET /api/1/orders/1234 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Accept: application/pdf
```

However, the situation changes a little bit if you clients are basically browsers because they normally send a generic Accept header when you type the URL in the address bar. You can check those values for common browsers such as Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Opera [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation).

For example, Chrome sends the following Accept header.

```
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9, text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
```

So in this case, what the browser is saying is that it prefers xml and html, if not plain text, png images or whatever other types. In this case it doesn't tell you any preference on neither json nor pdf (and the user can't easily specify that using the browser). In this case, it might be reasonable to have two URLs such as /api/1/orders/1234 (or /api/1/orders/1234.json) and /api/1/orders/1234.pdf.

So your choice will depend on what type of clients you anticipate. However, if it is two representations of the same resource more appropriate way to do that using HTTP would be to use content negotiation.